# How to select everything between two characters (> and <) except the characters themselves in MS Word

Tags: regex, ms-word

I am trying to build a REGEX expression to delete everything between two specific characters, that is, > and <, from a Microsoft Word 365 text. I have gotten to almost what I need but the characters > and < appear when they shouldn't appear.

I mean, this would be the **INPUT**: Click on **<tag>**. Todas as estruturas existentes serão aprovadas e se tornarão somente leitura. Para desaprovar o conjunto de estruturas, clique no botão **<tag>**

After using MS Word Regex - **\>*\<** -the **OUTPUT** I get is this: >. Todas as estruturas existentes serão aprovadas e se tornarão somente leitura. Para desaprovar o conjunto de estruturas, clique no botão <   that is, with > and <

I need to get this **OUTPUT**: . Todas as estruturas existentes serão aprovadas e se tornarão somente leitura.Para desaprovar o conjunto de estruturas, clique no botão

I need to **REMOVE** **>** and **<** from the REGEX expression.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want to select all between `>` and `<`. You want to remove all in between `<` and `>`, and also the text `Click on`. What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

Word does not support regex, it supports some variant of wildcards. This should work:

- Find: `*{1,}\<tag\>(*{1,})\<tag\>`
- Replace: `\1`
  Explanation:
- `*{1,}` - match one or more characters
- `\<` and `\>` - escape wildcard characters
- `(*{1,})` - capture text, reference in replace as `\1`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need RegEx for this - or even VBA. It can all be done with a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:
Find = <*>(*)<*>
Replace = \1